# How to add a custom font file in monaco editor

Tags: monaco-editor, visual-studio-monaco

the question is simple... Can I Use a custom font from a .ttf file in monaco-editor. If so... How do i do it,  because I have tried to send in `fontFamily: "monospace"` I have also tried to send in a custom font file like `fontFamily: "Fonts/SourceCodePro.ttf"` but it doesn't work...

[image: An Image Font not coming]

and here is the editor initialization

[image: here]

can someone help me...

Comment: It's like with any web page. You can only reference a font which is installed on the system or provide a font import somewhere. Search for how to use fonts on a web page.

Comment: i have already tried that using a websafe font, and importing a font the intended way and then using it but it still dosent work